# Does the human body need fat for other uses than to cover essential acid requirements?

Tags: nutrition

Linoleic acid and alpha linoleic acid are the two essential fatty acids, from which other fatty acids can be synthesized internally. See for example here: [Essential fatty acids](https://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/other-nutrients/essential-fatty-acids). Given that the requirements of these fatty acids are met, what other function do dietary fats provide which are unique to this macronutrient?

To clarify I'm asking about functions that must be provided by dietary fatty acids that cannot be provided by fatty acids synthesized from acetyl CoA from other dietary sources.

Comment: Surely by the definition of the word, essential, there can be none regarded as unique.

Comment: I have heard about fat being necessary (?) for the absorption of certain vitamines

Comment: But this is none-specific, and fatty acids can be synthesised from acetylCoA generated by the oxidation of carbohydrates etc.

Comment: You really need to clarify your question if you expect anyone to answer it with or without a bounty. Are you asking whether there are functions that must be provided by dietary fatty acids that cannot be provided by fatty acids synthesized from acetyl CoA from other dietary sources? (Incidentally, do you know what acetyl CoA is?) we can help you if we know what you are asking. If you don't know, you shouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 0):

Fats can serve non-metabolic functions as well, for example structure and support around organs, padding or insulation.